# Ensure custom view onRestoreInstanceState has been called

Tags: android, android-custom-view, onrestoreinstancestate

I need to get a callback from my custom view depending on whether it is being restored with a previously saved state.

Which view callback ensures that onRestoreInstanceState of a custom view has been called (or there is no instance state)? The onCreate of an activity passes a listener to the customView. I need to check if the customView has a restored state or not. I decided to call the listener success event on onRestoreInstanceState but this function is only called when there is a saved instance state. I think I am looking for a view lifecycle event which happens after onRestoreInstanceState and is also a guaranteed lifecycle event (so that I do not miss calling back the listener).

> protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Parcelable state)
>
> This function will never be called with a null state.

Is there a way inside a view to check if there is a savedInstanceState?

Edit: I am trying to make an aar SDK, so I do not have access to savedInstanceState in activity.onCreate callback or any other activity lifecycle event.

Comment: What about adding `if(savedInstanceState != null)` in your Activity's `onCreate()`?

Comment: I am trying to make an aar SDK, so I do not have access to savedInstanceState in activity.onCreate callback or any other activity lifecycle event.

Comment: I am now providing Fragment instead of a custom view and wrapped the early custom view within this fragment. I have been told Fragment is the recommended way of doing such things.